# Settings for php to solve empty session?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php

I have my php running on Centos 6.5 (Final). I have problem where one of my potential customer who is sitting remotely having upon login and redirect the sessions gets empty.He even tried on other machine or browser is the same within that network.  Below is the check list I have done.

1. Every top of the page there is session start
2. After the redirect statement I have put exit()
3. Customer have ensure cookies enabled.

What else can I do to overcome this issue? Could it be server side or client side issue ?